# Editing Text in a Nokogiri Element or Using Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

Is there a way to edit the text of a nokogiri element?  I have a nokogiri element that contains a list element (`<li>`) and I would like to remove some characters from the text while preserving the `<li>` html.  Specifically, I want to remove a leading ":" character in the text if it exists.  It doesn't look like there's a text= method for nokogiri elements, but I just wanted to make sure.

Maybe I will have to use regular expressions? If so, how would I remove a leading ":" if it looks something like:

```
<li>: blah blah blah</li>
```

p.s. I am using ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOS
  <ul>
    <li>: blah blah blah</li>
    <li>: foo bar baz</li>
  </ul>
EOS

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)
for li in doc.xpath('//li/text()')
  li.content = li.content.gsub(/^: */, '')
end
puts doc.to_html

# => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# => <html><body><ul>
# => <li>blah blah blah</li>
# =>     <li>foo bar baz</li>
# =>   </ul></body></html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `li.content = li.content.gsub(/^: */, '')` ?

Comment: @Daniel, You caught me.  This code went through some iterations before I posted it.  Then I noticed a variable name left over from a previous iteration, and decided it to just edit the answer to the good name.  But I missed one.

Comment: What about preserving links that are in the list element?

Comment: Just change the xpath to '//li/text()'.  I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot.  I also tried: definition.inner_html = definition.inner_html.gsub(/^: */, '') which seemed to work as well.